# Using the value of an alias inside the same sql statement

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I use the value of an alias for display in the same sql statement?

**For example:**

```
select now() as t, concat('Hello: ', username, t) from table;
```

What I'm actually trying to do is a lot more complex. I've broken it down to this so you get the idea.

How can something like this be done so I neednt select the same column again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not do that directly, but there's a way in MySQL to use variables like this:

```
select @t:=now() as t, concat('Hello: ', username, @t) from t;
```

If you don't need this `t` - you may want to remove that alias (I've kept just in case)

Comment: Oh Well! You ask, you learn. Thanks for this, made things so much easy for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can't re-use directly an alias in the select part of the same level of query.

You could use

a variable

```
select @myVar := now(), concat('Hello:', username, @myVar) from t;
```

a subquery

```
select concat('Hello:', username, t)
from (select now() as t, username from table1) s
```